# Packaging Visual Studio LoadTest Solution

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I have a VS 2010 Load test solution that contains quite a web tests and a bunch of Load tests. All of the web tests in this solution are data driven and use a SQL DB as the data source. Also, all of the data sources are set to random access method.

Now, whenever I change the data source or copy this solution to a different machine to test another deployment, I have to manually change the data source for all the web tests. The moment I change the data source, the access method gets reset to "sequential" which is the default setting. Now, I will have to change the access method also manually.

So, Is there a way I can package the VS Load Test solution so that the data source and access methods can be specified as parameters to the deployment package?

Note: Only the data source name changes but not the SQL DB schema for the data driven web tests.

Comment: Hi! Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not really. I looked at your solution. +1 for it as well. You solution seems to be the best as of now.

Comment: What knid of deployment package are you using? Is it an MSI?

Comment: I managed to make a text-box in an MSI installer, and had it build a config file with the connection string provided in that text-box... is that what you want? ... if it is, just tell, and I'll edit my answer to accomplish that too.

Comment: I ended up doing the same. My deployment package now has the required textboxes for all input and I modify the app.config before deploying the solution. Thanks. The bounty goes to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataSourceAttribute` can get all of it's properties from the configurations file of the application.

Here is a page that tells you how to use configuration files to place the connection string.

*[Walkthrough: Using a Configuration File to Define a Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243192.aspx)*

As you can see you may place the connection string in the **app.config** file, in the section `<microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools>`:

```
<microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
        <add name="MyJetDataSource" connectionString="MyJetConn" dataTableName="MyDataTable" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
        <add name="MyExcelDataSource" connectionString="MyExcelConn" dataTableName="Sheet1$" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
</microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

In code usage of attribute:

```
[DataSource("MyJetDataSource")]
```

**Reference:**

The following links are just for reference:

[How to: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) : creating data-sriven tests

[Working with Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182561%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) : understanding load tests

[DataSourceAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) : docs for the attribute

[DataSourceAttribute Constructor (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243349.aspx) : ctor that allows external connection string

[DataSourceAttribute.DataSourceSettingName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datasourceattribute.datasourcesettingname.aspx)

Comment: I am also marking this as the answer since I am using the solution provided by you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Covert the web tests into coded web tests. In the code you will see the data binding code. Whenever you change the data source you can simply use find and replace all for data source name.
I don't think there is way to include this in deployment package.

Comment: I am doing this currently. This won't scale. +1 in any case.